# Validar mais de um input Campo CPF

Tags: javascript, validação

Tenho esse Script para validação de CPF. Porém em meu formulário, existe mais de um campo que necessita da validação do CPF, dentro de uma tabela que vai adicionando conforme aperta o botão adicionar. Como devo fazer para que o script valide esses outros dois campos ?

> Script Validação CPF

```
function CPF(){"user_strict";function r(r){
                    for(
                        var t=null,n=0;9>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(10-n);
                        var i=t%11;return i=2>i?0:11-i}
                function t(r){
                    for(
                        var t=null,n=0;10>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(11-n);var i=t%11;
                        return i=2>i?0:11-i}
                        var n="CPF Inválido",i="CPF Válido";this.gera=
                function(){
                    for(
                        var n="",i=0;9>i;++i)n+=Math.floor(9*Math.random())+"";
                        var o=r(n),a=n+"-"+o+t(n+""+o);
                        return a},this.valida=
                function(o){
                    for(
                        var a=o.replace(/\D/g,""),u=a.substring(0,9),f=a.substring(9,11),v=0;10>v;v++)
                        if(""+u+f==""+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v)
                            return n;var c=r(u),e=t(u+""+c);
                            return f.toString()===c.toString()+e.toString()?i:n}}

                        var CPF = new CPF();                        
                    for(var i =0;i<40;i++) {
                        var temp_cpf = CPF.gera();                          
                            //document.write(temp_cpf+" = "+CPF.valida(temp_cpf)+"<br>");
                    }

                    $("#input").keypress(function(){
                        $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
                    });

                    $("#input").blur(function(){
                        $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
                    });
```

> Campo dentro da Tabela

```
<td><input class="form-control" style="width: 180px" type="text" id="cpfFilial" name="cpfFilial" mask="000.000.000-00" >
```

> E

`<td><input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 100%;" id="cpfContCliente" name="cpfContCliente" mask="000.000.000-00"></td>`

O primeiro campo CPF que está fora de tabelas, é apenas um input normal, esta validando corretamente.

Os campos que também precisam da validação são:
cpfFilial e cpfContCliente

Quando acionado o botão "novo" na tabela, eles ficam assim :

cpfFilial___1 / cpfFilial___2 / cpfContCliente___1 / cpfContCliente___2

Comment: Me parece que o codigo que você postou está incompleto. Esse é o codigo completo?

Comment: O Script? está completo sim !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notei que está usando jQuery, acredito que consegue fazer dessa forma:

```
$(document).on('blur keyup', "input[name^='cpf']",function() {
        $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});
```

`^` é um seletor de critério [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Lucas, Não funcionou!

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: Não. console em braco. e o campo que estava funcionando corretamente, parou de funcionar.

Comment: É possível fazer um [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Simplifiquei o HTML e deixei os dois últimos campos dentro das tabelas das quais os dois ultimos inputs estão dentro. https://jsfiddle.net/kapinheiro/nsrsc3xe/

Comment: Lembrando que o primeiro input, funciona corretamente apesar de não aparecer no jsfiddle

Comment: Perdão, falha minha no uso das aspás. Veja agora: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/nsrsc3xe/1/

Comment: Lucas, Funcionou apenas o primeiro input.

Comment: vc comentou que errou no uso das aspas, mas o fiddle que mandou, está igual ao primeiro.

Comment: Não está @KarinaPinheiro, note que está `"input[name^='cpf']"` e não `'input[name^='cpf']'` como estava antes. Coloquei um CPF válido no terceiro input ele validou, se eu retiro algum numero ele troca a mensagem para CPF inválido. O que não está funcionando? A forma como a mensagem é exibiba? http://imgur.com/a/K8lAl

Comment: Lucas, está funcionando sim. o que eu não tinha reparado, é que a resposta aparece lá no primeiro input. achei que aparecia na frente do input que foi digitado.

Comment: E notei outra coisa, o ideal é usar keyup e não keypress, pois keypress obtém até o penultimo valor digitado e não o atual, ou seja, ele vai considerar sempre o valor menos o que foi digitado por último. Veja agora: https://jsfiddle.net/nsrsc3xe/2/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58072/discussion-between-karina-pinheiro-and-lucas-costa).

Comment: @KarinaPinheiro em jQuery Não é necessário criar um `on` para cada evento, basta agrupar assim: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/11d3d47d9ba7ce62b2566ddbd0493f96

Comment: Boa @GuilhermeNascimento, editei com sua sugestão